# Local Database File stored using DropBox

Tags: c#, database, dropbox

I am actually developing a multi users application where people can store their own informations into a local database. Now, there is another database file storing al of people's data. I am looking for alternatives to a MySQL server (no budget of course...).
And DropBox (or Cloud storage) came to mind.

Is it possible to use DropBox to store the main Database .mdf file and make it available to people when they want to get their data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do this.

1. Access does not scale well to multiple users/medium sized databases.

   - Access has a size limit of 2GB (this can be gotten around in some cases).
   - Maximum of 255 concurrent users
2. Drop box can't synchronize the differences if two users modify the main database at the same time.  Remember with Dropbox you are modifying the file locally and then uploading a new version every time it changes.

Basically if you want to support multiple users and you want a shared database, you either have to have a central server to host all of the data or some sort of client level synchronization that allows the clients to each have a copy of the full database and changes are synced among all clients.

Comment: Even though I have 25 to 30 users maximum ? Users don't download the whole database, only the data they are linked to.
I thought working around with SQL queries would be enough to override the need of downloading the complete file.

Comment: @user2071260 MSAccess requires file system level access to the database file and creates a lock file to handle user contention. So many shared MSAccess databases are hosted on a UNC share.

Comment: I see. I am gonna have to find a way to make 'em buy a damn computer to host the database.